# How to create a timer/counter in C# XNA

Tags: c#, timer, xna, clock, game-development

I'm fairly new to C# programming, and this is my first time using it in XNA. I'm trying to create a game with a friend, but we're struggling on making a basic counter/clock. What we require is a timer that starts at 1, and every 2 seconds, +1, with a maximum capacity of 50. Any help with the coding would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To create a timer in XNA you could use something like this:

```
int counter = 1;
int limit = 50;
float countDuration = 2f; //every  2s.
float currentTime = 0f;

currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; //Time passed since last Update() 

if (currentTime >= countDuration)
{
    counter++;
    currentTime -= countDuration; // "use up" the time
    //any actions to perform
}
if (counter >= limit)
{
    counter = 0;//Reset the counter;
    //any actions to perform
}
```

I am by no means an expert on C# or XNA as well, so I appreciate any hints/suggestions.

Comment: I have decided to go with something like the answer you gave me; however, I can't figure out what action should be performed with .TotalSeconds it's the only error I am now recieving. Is there any way you could help me with this?
EDIT: The error I'm recieving with this is "'NullReferenceException was unhandled' Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: You can only have that error because of gameTime, so a) you are not passing GameTime to the method, b) you are not using this in an Update method or c) both!

gameTime must be a parameter that you receive from the standard loop in XNA.

Comment: If ElapsedGameTime is the time passed since last Update() function, it doesn't make sense to use TotalSeconds attribute. For MonoGame (which has taken the basics of XNA), it's better to use the TotalMilliseconds attribute for animations. For Game timers, it's good to use TotalGameTime instead of ElapsedGameTime

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the XNA ElapsedTime you can use the c# timer. You can find tutorials about that, here the [msdn reference for timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Anyway here is some code that do more or less what you want.

First, you need to declare in your class something like that:

```
    Timer lTimer = new Timer();
    uint lTicks = 0;
    static uint MAX_TICKS = 50;
```

Then you need to init the timer whereever you want

```
    private void InitTimer()
    {
        lTimer       = new Timer();
        lTimer.Interval = 2000; 
        lTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        lTimer.Start();
    }
```

then in the Tick eventhandler you should do whatever you want to do every 50 ticks.

```
    void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lTicks++;
        if (lTicks <= MAX_TICKS)
        {
            //do whatever you want to do
        }
    }
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try out both and see what feels most suitable.

Comment: -1. XNA is not an event-based API. Using an event-based timer is unidiomatic. Using the elapsed time is appropriate.