# Creating a timer in Monogame. Creating an event after 5 seconds

Tags: c#, time, counter, monogame

I have some troubles with creating a timer for my c# monogame. I already red the other timer questions on stack overflow, but I didn't get it.
I want to collect gold in my mine. But the gold is limited, every 5 seconds there should be new gold.
I tried to do it like [How to create a timer/counter in C# XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394892/how-to-create-a-timer-counter-in-c-sharp-xna?rq=1) 
But it isn't working. I get a System.NullReferenceException. Is there a better way to do a timer? Or how can I fix the Exception?

Here is the most important part of my code:

```
private GameTime gameTime;
int counter = 1;
int limit = 50;
float countDuration = 10f; //every  2s.
float currentTime = 0f;

private void CollectGold(ObjectFactory.ObjectType type)
{ 
    currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; //Time passed since last Update()
    if (currentTime >= countDuration)
    {
        counter++;
        currentTime -= countDuration;
        // maxGold limits the Mine 
        if (mMaxGold > 0)
        {
            mGold += 5;
            mMaxGold -= 10;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly isnt working.. Im not familiar with monogame specifically, did XNA and unity..  what exactly is null? gameTime would be my guess possibly...

Comment: Where do you assign the value of the `gameTime` variable?

Comment: yes, game time is null.

Answer (score 0):

thank. I did it. Just assign the value of GameTime wrong. Didn't know that it have to be in an update function. Thanks.